# When i try to debug my project it throws no such file error

Tags: java, spring, debugging

So the problem is that my [project](https://github.com/Similization/simple_dictionari_api_for_gallows_game_project.git) do not debug correctly, it is pretty big so i can not figure out when it started throw this error:

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mntBE.jpg)

`java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/similization/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-18.0.1.1/Contents/Home/conf/jndi.properties`

**P.S.** I tried to use another versions of tomcat and tried to reinstall everything, but nothing changed and also none of my JVM version have such file (`jndi.properties`). When i just run my project - everything works fine but i'd like to have debug ability. After i stopped debugging my project i got this message from IntelliJ Idea:

```
Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: 
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Catalina:type=Server
```

**UPDATE 1**

Here is a full
[stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzQ8q.jpg)

```
"java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)"
"java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)"
"java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)"
"java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:218)"
"java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:380)"
"java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:432)"
"java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:422)"
"java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:160)"
"java.naming/com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper.lambda$getJavaHomeConfStream$4(VersionHelper.java:228)"
"java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)" "java.naming/com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper.getJavaHomeConfStream(VersionHelper.java:233)"
"java.naming/com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.getApplicationResources(ResourceManager.java:530)"
"java.naming/com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.getInitialEnvironment(ResourceManager.java:188)"
"java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:232)"
"java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:184)"
"org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:99)"
"org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:82)"
"org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)"
"org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)"
"org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)"
"org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:923)"
"org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)"
"org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)"
"java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)"
"java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)"
"org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)"
"org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)"
```

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace *as text* into your question - and then ideally work on reproducing this in a minimal project.

Comment: I see the mention of Linux, and a path `"/Users/..."`. As paths are case sensitive, it just might be a true error and it should be `/users/...`.

Answer (score 0):

there maybe 2 diffrent posssblity
1.there should be run time error
2.your file name has mis matched javac **MyFirstJavaProgram. java**'
or can you just share image of your code

Comment: Why nobody like links on projects? Which images of code do you need?